# How get date from elasticsearch with one format?

Tags: date, datetime, elasticsearch

I have create an index like that:

```
PUT twitter

PUT twitter/_mapping/myType
{
    "myType" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "date",
            "date_detection": true,
            "store" : true }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I put several documents:

```
POST twitter/myType
{
    "message":123456
}
```

I have this document and other with `message` values: "123456",-123456,"2014-01-01","-123456" (**Note** string and numeric difference here). Only document with value "12@3454" failed to put.

So now I execute:

```
GET twitter/myType/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*
```

And results are:

```
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "twitter",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "AU5JvFsHvhUOO_5MdfCv",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "message": -123456
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "twitter",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "AU5Ju6aOvhUOO_5MdfCs",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "message": "123456"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "twitter",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "AU5Ju0KOvhUOO_5MdfCq",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "message": "2014-01-01"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "twitter",
            "_type": "myType",
            "_id": "AU5JvDiGvhUOO_5MdfCu",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "message": "-123456"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Why I get these value in date fields instead of string value - [ISODateTimeFormat.dateOptionalTimeParser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)? Is there a way to get all date with one format (e.g. string or millis)?

Elasticsearch version is 1.4.3

Comment: did you try an explicit setting of format in message property of mapping like `format: 'dateOptionalTime'`

Answer (score 2):

That's the `_source` you are seeing, meaning the exact JSON you indexed, no formatting, nothing.
If you want to see what actually ES indexed (meaning the date in milliseconds), you can use `fielddata_fields`:

```
GET /twitter/myType/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "message"
  ]
}
```

And the answer to your question is that is not actually available out-of-the-box. You need to use `script_fields`:

```
GET /twitter/myType/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "message"
  ],
  "_source": "*", 
  "script_fields": {
    "my_script": {
      "script": "new Date(doc[\"message\"].value)"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, your mapping is wrong: `date_detection` should be put in the type not in the field:

```
PUT twitter
{
  "mappings": {
    "myType": {
      "date_detection": true,
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "date",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And from the output below you'll see how ES treats those numbers you put in there:

```
     {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "AU5J93Q-I7tQJ10g6jk5",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "message": "123456"
        },
        "fields": {
           "message": [
              3833727840000000
           ],
           "my_script": [
              "123456-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "AU5J93Q-I7tQJ10g6jk4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "message": 123456
        },
        "fields": {
           "message": [
              123456
           ],
           "my_script": [
              "1970-01-01T00:02:03.456Z"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "AU5J93Q-I7tQJ10g6jk8",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "message": "-123456"
        },
        "fields": {
           "message": [
              -3958062278400000
           ],
           "my_script": [
              "-123456-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "AU5J93Q-I7tQJ10g6jk7",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "message": "2014-01-01"
        },
        "fields": {
           "message": [
              1388534400000
           ],
           "my_script": [
              "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "AU5J93Q-I7tQJ10g6jk6",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "message": -123456
        },
        "fields": {
           "message": [
              -123456
           ],
           "my_script": [
              "1969-12-31T23:57:56.544Z"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

Comment: How did the documents get indexed even though they are not of the date format?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna look at the list of documents ES is returning and you'll see what actually ES is indexing.

Comment: Ok. My main question was why is ES even allowing the PUT request to be successful, when the given value is not of a date format. I'm talking about the mapping provided by OP. Not the script mapping you have provided.